# AWS CLI: 'import-image'

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ec2

I configured the EC2 CLI interface on a  [Win10 box](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-msi-on-windows) per the [instructions (click here)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/set-up-ec2-cli-windows.html)

This CLI was installed so a [to create a new import image task](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ImportVMImportImage.html):

> > import-image --description "Windows 2008 OVA" --disk-containers file://containers.json

I searched through the EC2 CLI commands and did not see 'import-image'.  Isn't this command part of the EC2 CLI set?

[image]

A nudge in the right direction is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are on version 1.7.5.1 but awscli got support for import-image in version 1.7.24, see here

[https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI?c=25&p=4&sm=dD][1]